# PFFile & Image Issue: Image != nil, but does not appear after initial log in

Tags: ios, caching, parse-platform, uiimageview, nsdata

My app uses parse.  Right after you log in, data is extracted from Parse.  In this, the PFFile for an image is extracted too.  If the image for the PFFile is not already cached, I call getDataInBackground and set the image property of the object being populated equal to nil.  After getDataInBackground says it has retrieved the image data, meaning it is now cached on the device as Parse does, I call refresh which extracts the data from Parse again and is supposed to pull the image from the local cache since it is now there.  At this point, the image does not equal nil (which I set it equal to if it is not cached), but does not appear on the cell.  However, if I close the app, turn it off and reopen it, the images appear.  I do not know why it only fails immediately after log in but then works after I shut down the app (such that it isn't running in the background) then run it again.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to cell reuse. When the image equals nil, I hid the image view. When the image was extracted and I set it to be the image view's image, I never marked the image view as visible. Reusing the cell means I had to reset this for it to appear.